# Export variables Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have a bash script that does:

`export VAR="ABCD"`

This works if I am in command line and do:

`source script.sh`

But if I am using `exec` in Node.js, the script runs but the variable doesnt change if I try `echo $VAR` afterwards in command line.

Is there a fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: Because it just updates it in the exec session. Try running in your exec `export VAR="ABCD" && echo $VAR`.

Comment: @FrançoisP., how can I update it globally?

Comment: Appart from editing the `/etc/profile` there is no way, this is for security reasons.